# Editing parse database form the Parse.com

Tags: database, parse-platform, backend

I want to add a row in my parse database from the website but I am not able to do so.

I basically want to add details using the parse online data browser.

I log in to parse open my app and go to my database where my data is stored I select a database and when I click "**+Row**" it creates a row with everything filled "**(undefined)**" and I am not able to change the column values.

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Just double click on the cell and you'll enter the edit mode

Comment: I removed the opening Hello and uppercased a few i's